# How to judge domain switch strict mode in react18

Tags: reactjs, vite

I want to modify the behavior of strict mode in my project based on the environment variables and the website being visited. I have two environment variables, .env.development and .env.production, and two corresponding websites, https://dev... and https://prod...

Strict mode should only be enabled on localhost during development to catch errors, but should be turned off in the https environment. I am using console.log to check the value of the variable shouldUseStrictMode which currently shows as true on localhost and false on https://dev...

However, I am encountering an issue where the useEffect hook is being rendered twice even though the shouldUseStrictMode variable is correctly changing. Is there a way for strict mode to use the enabled setting to determine its activation?

```
const isLocalhost = window.location.hostname === "localhost";
const shouldUseStrictMode =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" && isLocalhost;

console.log("Current hostname:", window.location.hostname);
console.log("NODE_ENV:", process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log("shouldUseStrictMode:", shouldUseStrictMode);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode enabled={shouldUseStrictMode}>
    <IconContext.Provider
      value={{ className: "text-slate-500", size: "1.25rem" }}
    >
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </IconContext.Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strict mode does not accept any props. If you want to not render a strict mode element, you will need to leave the element out entirely. For example:

```
const isLocalhost = window.location.hostname === "localhost";
const shouldUseStrictMode =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" && isLocalhost;

const elements = (
  <IconContext.Provider
    value={{ className: "text-slate-500", size: "1.25rem" }}
  >
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </IconContext.Provider>
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  shouldUseStrictMode ? (
    <React.StrictMode>{elements}</React.StrictMode>
  ) : (
    elements
  )
);
```

But... I'm surprised you would need this at all. Strict mode automatically disables itself if you do a production build of react. If you're seeing double renders in production, maybe you've accidentally done a dev build instead of a prod build, or maybe you have other code which is causing the extra renders.

Comment: I am not sure at the moment, in which link did I have this problem

I want to achieve the same effect in web pages with dev and prod environment variables

Comment: I tested the method you provided successfully, thank you